# how to configure drupal commerce product attributes?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I am developing a drupal website using commerce module for a cake shop client. I need to add a two attributes namely 'kg' and 'flavor'. Depending on this two attributes the price should change.
I have worked on drupal ubercart modules, there i could get those above attributes using attributes in the configuration. but how can i get these attributes using commerce modules?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create two taxonomies (better for search by..., But it can be a simple text field) "kg" and "flavor", next add to the product (commerce product) two Term reference field ensuring enabled in the options field: "Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms." and set Number of Values ​​to 1.

Now create the products, one for each attribute
Product A - Xkg - Yflavor
Prodcut B - XXkg - YYflavor

Next create a new product (content type) and reference all the productos.

END
Regards!

Comment: The hint *Term reference field* was very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

After installing drupal commerce module go to following link to configure product with price and attribute :

1. www.domainname.com/admin/commerce
2. www.domainname.com/admin/commerce/product-attributes/add  (Add attribute here Ex. 'kg' and 'flavor')
3. www.domainname.com/product/add/default (here you can see you previously added attribute as option while adding product info and base on list of attribute you can add price for each of theme.